# Ruby: cannot install libv8 on Windows 7 : missing python installation

Tags: python, ruby

my question is too many on Google but I still cannot find the real answer.

First, I run `rails server` : error missing libv8

I try `bundle install` and notice that cannot install libv8 library because missing Python.

But I have installed Python before at put it into Path. For example: `D:\...:\Python\` : notice that not `Python\bin` because python doesn't have bin folder.

I have read some tutorial on internet, has tried to install `DevKit` too, but no result.

Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Please see my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812696/problems-with-jslint-v8-ruby-gem-installation-on-windows7-64-bit/10924081#10924081

Comment: @LuisLavena oh, as your post, I cannot run ruby gem on Windows ? And if I have google chrome, can I install it. Because I remember, Google use V8 Engine to run JavaScript.

Comment: Having Google Chrome has nothing to do with the gem. Google uses V8 *internally* so the gem needs it's own version. If you need libv8 for jslint or something like that, why not use node directly instead of going through ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the DevKit you need Python to be installed and included in your path. 
There are several Python installers for windows on the [Python Dowload Page](http://www.python.org/download/).

My first attempt with Python 3.2.3 failed, because it is not supported by libv8. 
My second attempt with **2.7** succeeded!