# Jruby installation for ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I'm trying to install Jruby on ROR for my application. Used commands from its documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby . While bundle installation got the following errors

1. Your Ruby engine is ruby, but your Gemfile specified jruby
2. Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Furthermore certain gems are not installed successfully, shows error like 
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Not able to find the issue. Would somebody help with this ?

Gemfile :

```
ruby '1.9.3', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '1.7.9'
gem "rake"
gem "rails", "3.2.16"
gem 'foreigner'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
gem 'jruby'
gem 'airbrake'
gem "spreadsheet", "~> 0.9.0"
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => nil
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'mail', :require => nil
gem 'fastercsv', :require => nil
gem "rspec-rails"
gem 'rubyzip', :require => nil
gem 'test-unit'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'thin'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'useragent'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'libv8', '3.16.14.3'
```

Comment: yes ! Using commands from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby

Comment: please post your gemfile

Comment: Have posted it ! @GregoryOstermayr

Comment: I added the last two gem as it showed error on that ! is it rite ? libv8 gem was not in gemfile but why did it show issue on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use 'therubyracer' and 'libv8' gems with JRuby.

Short answer:

Use 'therubyrhino' gem instead (https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino)

Explanation:

There are some gems that can't be used under JRuby, because they are using native (C) extensions - here is a list: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to install all below libraries, before installing Ruby/RVM.

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev build-essential openssl libssl-dev libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libyaml-dev
```

Before JRuby installation.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
rvm install jruby
```

Don't specify Jruby version, default you will get latest version.

Comment: Finished with installation and i bundle installed the gems and got the same error again "Installing libv8 (3.16.14.3) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Comment: Used this command "gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'" and retried. Still getting error ! Why does that happen for this gem ?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673714/rails-gem-install-error-error-installing-libv8-error-failed-to-build-gem-nati