# Why can't rails find my gems after I bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I have a rails application. When I run `bundle install` I see all the gems installing and at the end of everything I see this message.

```
Bundle complete! 71 Gemfile dependencies, 180 gems now installed.
```

However when I execute `rails s`. I get this message:

```
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri-1.6.8
Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json-1.8.3
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller-0.7.2
Ignoring bluecloth-2.2.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bluecloth-2.2.0
Could not find libv8-3.16.14.15 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Why does this happen? I've already ran `bundle install` and when I then use `bundle show json` I get this `/Users/drubio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@ohloh-ui/gems/json-1.8.3`

The same goes for all the other gems. What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673714/error-installing-libv8-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: are you sure that rails uses the same ruby version as bundler?
you can try to specify ruby version in your Gemfile

Comment: and it looks like the gems itself are installed but their native extensions weren't  built during bundle install.
did you have any warning during bundle install?

Comment: Hey Dinesh, the link to that answer helped big time and I got it resolved. I'm still not sure how that happened but its fine now.