# gem install libv8 -v '5.3.332.38.1' ... Error installing libv8: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos

Any ideas/suggestions?

**** Further update:****
2.3.1 agxxx-xxxight 2290-fix-claim-button % ruby -e 'puts Gem::Platform.local'
x86_64-darwin-13

I have 2 machines which i am trying to get lib v8 on.... and now getting same errors (regardless of darwin v.)
1 a mac desktop (with x86_64-darwin-13 but the other with darwin-16).  Initially, I thought the issue was to do with darwin-13 but now getting this same issue regardless).

---

I have tried a number of solutions from reinstalling & upgrading both OSX and xcode.

Mac OX Sierra 10.12.3
xcode 8.2.1

I see a similar Stack overflow but mentions rubyracer and not sure if this is related to that?  [Error installing libv8: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673714/error-installing-libv8-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Here's my error:

gem install libv8 -v '5.3.332.38.1'
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    current directory: /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/ext/libv8
/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170209-5158-fzzx9o.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Error: Command 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=darwin --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/mac/clang-format.sha1' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/vendor
Running: gclient root
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "managed": False,
    "name": "v8",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "custom_deps": {},
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "safesync_url": "",
  },
]
'
Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 353, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 348, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 342, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 142, in init
    self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
  File "/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 76, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/vendor/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 66, in run
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'sync', '--with_branch_heads')' returned non-zero exit status 2
/Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:106:in `block in setup_build_deps!': unable to fetch v8 source (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:104:in `chdir'
    from /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:104:in `setup_build_deps!'
    from /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:60:in `build_libv8!'
    from /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-5.3.332.38.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/axxxsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.3.0-static/libv8-5.3.332.38.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I recently upgraded to Mac Sierra (reinstalled my hard drive), down loaded new versions of Chrome & Google Drive.  I am wondering is this incompatibility with newest version of Sierra?  Any one else having this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this (requires Homebrew):

```
brew install v8
gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
```

For a specific version:

```
gem install libv8 -v '5.3.332.38.1' -- --with-system-v8
```

but I'm assuming the version number would need to match whatever the Homebrew formula version of v8 is.

Comment: Hi - Thank you - this got me past this issue.

Comment: you can also use a gem like therubyracer to package your own v8 lib with your app so then you aren't reliant on system install